# Can we display facebook application on user profile?

Tags: facebook, canvas

I have a Facebook application which is displayed on canvas page like all other Facebook applications but I want to display application on users profile page like Facebook's find friends,messages applications so that left panel displaying Favourites, Apps,groups are visible to user.

Answer (score 1):

No - this is not possible.  Tab applications can only appear on Facebook Pages.